# app crashes after running npm start command

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I am following the steps of angular quickstart, but in the end, after running "npm start" it gives me following errors:

```
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(46,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(44,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(347,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(348,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(19,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(21,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(19,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(43,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(424,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts(13,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(45,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(47,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(25,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(26,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(106,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(122,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(148,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(150,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(28,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(88,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(88,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(5,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(6,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.8
3 info using node@v6.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\user\Desktop\angular-2\angular-quickstart\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\user\Desktop\angular-2\angular-quickstart
11 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" ' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
14 verbose stack Exit status 2
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\angular-2\angular-quickstart
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.9.1
20 error npm  v3.10.8
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and one more thing: when I change tsconfig.json's "target" option from "es5" to "es6" , app starts running.
please help.

Comment: Did you do `npm install`?

Comment: yes, couple of times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/core-js
```

in tsconfig in compilerOptions add:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [
  "core-js"
]
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works well. can you please explain what was I doing wrong and what did this lines do?